# How to make this bit of code in R go faster? I am checking if values of a vector belong to a range and I return a logical vector

Tags: r, performance, vector

So I have an input vector "Vin", and I have two a dataframes to compare with that vector. These dataframes DMAX and DMIN contain the range of values I want to check that my input values are within their ranges in their respective positions.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DMIN)){
V2 <- Vin >= DMIN[i,2:521] & Vin <= DMAX[i,2:521]
V1[i] <- length(V2[V2 == FALSE])
}
```

I have noticed that the V2 calculation is slow and maybe R is doing it value by value instead of all the vector.

Please help. Sorry if there is any bad formatting it's my first post.

Comment: what is `j` here?

Comment: Sorry it's meant to be i. I have it in a nested loop to check a list of vectors. I edited it.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your data and expected output.  There are a couple ways to improve performance, but without a sample it is impossible to read your mind.

Comment: I think you _should_ adopt the practice of expressing your intent in natural language for all your programming problems. And adopt the practice in posting to SO of constructing a small example (obviously much smaller than 500+ columns) to support demonstrations. It's very possible that you are not getting the results you desire, and it's pretty clear you are not being effective at the moment in communicating your situation.

Comment: You are right Mr 42. It's the first time I ever post a question. I am self taught and I have never discussed my code with anybody. I am a total noob here so forgive my ignorance pls.

I come from MAtlab and I was used to doing operations in whole matrices or vectors really fast. I was wondering if there was a way to do the same in R.

Answer (score 5):

Let me try to demonstrate what I'm preaching above. First a small concrete example:

```
setseed(1949)
Dmin <- as.data.frame( matrix( runif(80), 10) )
Dmax <- as.data.frame( matrix( runif(80), 10) )
for (i in 1:nrow(Dmin)){
V2 <- Vin >= Dmin[i,2:8] & Vin <= Dmax[i,2:8]
V1[i] <- length(V2[V2 == FALSE])
}
V1
# [1] 5 6 5 4 7 6 4 7 6 3
```

Generally attempting to find a solution that uses a vectorized function like rowSums will be more efficient. I *think* you wnat the row counts of the numbers of items on columns 2-8 (or 521 in your case) for which Vin is not in the the ranges for each col-row pairing of DMAX and DMIN (although I don't like holding down shift-keys, so they are named Dmin abd Dmax)):

This seems to deliver a "loop-free" solution:

```
(V1 <-rowSums( !( Vin >= Dmin[-1] &Vin <= Dmax[-1])  ) )
 [1] 5 6 5 4 7 6 4 7 6 3
```

Comment: I'll be looking into that the whole day today. Many thanks!